# Cómo obtener los datos de los inputs con método POST o GET, con botón ocultar / mostrar?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Necesito saber cómo obtener los datos ingresados con método **POST** o **GET** luego de mostrar y ocultar los `inputs` .
Tengo un código que solo muestra y oculta `inputs` con botones, pero no envia todos los datos de todos los `inputs` con método POST.

Este es mi código:

```js
 var ctr = 0;
        var ctr_bdra = 0;
        var init = 0;
        var contenedor = $(".inputs");
        var edad = $(".edad_hidden");
        var edades;

        $(".agregar").click(function(e){            
            add_control(contenedor);
            $(".agregar, .nth").hide(); 
            e.preventDefault();
        });


        $(document).on('click', 'button.agregar_in', function(e){
            if($(".ed").val() == "")
            {
                return false;

            }else{
                add_control(contenedor);
                ctr_bdra = 1;
                if(ctr_bdra > 0){
                    $(this).hide();
                    
                    $(this).next().hide();
                }

            }
            e.preventDefault();

        });

        $(document).on('click', 'button.eliminar_in', function(e){ 
            array = $(".edad_hidden").val().split(',');
            array.pop();
            $(".edad_hidden").val(array);
            var node = $(this).parent();
            node.remove();
            if(!$(".btun").is(":visible")){
                $(".agregar, .nth").show();
            }           
            $('button.agregar_in').last().show();
            
            $('button.eliminar_in').last().show();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $(document).on('keyup','.ed', function() {
            var info = [];
            $('.ed').each(function(){ info.push($(this).val()); });
            $(".edad_hidden").val(info);
        });


        function add_control(contenedor){
            ctr = ctr + 1;
            contenedor.append('<div class="btun"><input type="number" min="0" class="ed" name="edades" value=""  id="tb' + ctr + '' +'"/>'+
                              '<button class="agregar_in">+</button>'+
                              '<button class="eliminar_in">-</button></div>');
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" >
      <p class="nth" style="display: inline-block;">Agregar</p>
      <button class="agregar">+</button>
      <div class="inputs"></div>
      <input type="hidden" value  class="edad_hidden"></input>   
      <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
    </form>
    
    <?php
$envio=$_POST['edades'];
    echo $envio;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando hacés `.append()` de la función `add_control()` en vez de ponerle de nombre al `input` como `name="edades"`, lo reemplazaría por `name="edades[]"` para que tome el valor como un array por cada input que ingresas. Debería quedar así:

```
function add_control(contenedor) {
  ctr = ctr + 1;
  contenedor.append(
    '<div class="btun"><input type="number" min="0" class="ed" name="edades[]" value=""  id="tb' +
      ctr +
      "" +
      '"/>' +
      '<button class="agregar_in">+</button>' +
      '<button class="eliminar_in">-</button></div>'
  );
}
```

Luego en el PHP vas a recibir algo como lo siguiente:

```
var_dump($_POST['edades']);
```

Esto imprime un `array`.

---

```js
 var ctr = 0;
        var ctr_bdra = 0;
        var init = 0;
        var contenedor = $(".inputs");
        var edad = $(".edad_hidden");
        var edades;

        $(".agregar").click(function(e){            
            add_control(contenedor);
            $(".agregar, .nth").hide(); 
            e.preventDefault();

        });


        $(document).on('click', 'button.agregar_in', function(e){
            if($(".ed").val() == "")
            {
                return false;

            }else{
                add_control(contenedor);
                ctr_bdra = 1;
                if(ctr_bdra > 0){
                    $(this).hide();
                    
                    $(this).next().hide();
                }

            }
            e.preventDefault();

        });

        $(document).on('click', 'button.eliminar_in', function(e){ 
            array = $(".edad_hidden").val().split(',');
            array.pop();
            $(".edad_hidden").val(array);
            var node = $(this).parent();
            node.remove();
            if(!$(".btun").is(":visible")){
                $(".agregar, .nth").show();
            }           
            $('button.agregar_in').last().show();
            
            $('button.eliminar_in').last().show();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $(document).on('keyup','.ed', function() {
            var info = [];
            $('.ed').each(function(){ info.push($(this).val()); });
            $(".edad_hidden").val(info);
        });


        function add_control(contenedor){
            ctr = ctr + 1;
            contenedor.append('<div class="btun"><input type="number" min="0" class="ed" name="edades[]" value=""  id="tb' + ctr + '' +'"/>'+
                              '<button class="agregar_in">+</button>'+
                              '<button class="eliminar_in">-</button></div>');
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <p class="nth" style="display: inline-block;">Agregar</p>
  <button class="agregar">+</button>
  <div class="inputs"></div>
  <input type="hidden" value class="edad_hidden" />
  <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: muchas gracias mano , lo probaré a ver que sucede

Comment: man una consulta , ahora como hago para grabar estos  numeros en un solo campo en base de datos php con mysql.

Comment: Eso es otra pregunta pero podés hacer un [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) del `array` como `$edades = implode(',', $_POST['edades']);`. Entonces eso te genera un `string` y ya podés insertarlo en la DB sin problemas.

Comment: ok , excelente. ahroa he colgado otra pregunta parecido , en vez de los input aparezcan los slider de JQuery UI

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166097/como-mostrar-ocultar-sliders-de-jquery-ui-con-botones