# Como mostrar/ocultar Sliders de Jquery UI con botones

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una consulta como puedo hacer para que en vez que se muestren y oculten los input tipo number se muestren y oculten los slider de Jquery UI.

Osea Reemplazar inputs por Sliders

dejo código ...

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
    $( "#slider2" ).slider();
    $( "#slider3" ).slider();
    $( "#slider4" ).slider();
    $( "#slider5" ).slider();
    $( "#slider6" ).slider();
  } );


 var ctr = 0;
        var ctr_bdra = 0;
        var init = 0;
        var contenedor = $(".inputs");
        var edad = $(".edad_hidden");
        var edades;

        $(".agregar").click(function(e){            
            add_control(contenedor);
            $(".agregar, .nth").hide(); 
            e.preventDefault();

        });


        $(document).on('click', 'button.agregar_in', function(e){
            if($(".ed").val() == "")
            {
                return false;

            }else{
                add_control(contenedor);
                ctr_bdra = 1;
                if(ctr_bdra > 0){
                    $(this).hide();
                    
                    $(this).next().hide();
                }

            }
            e.preventDefault();

        });

        $(document).on('click', 'button.eliminar_in', function(e){ 
            array = $(".edad_hidden").val().split(',');
            array.pop();
            $(".edad_hidden").val(array);
            var node = $(this).parent();
            node.remove();
            if(!$(".btun").is(":visible")){
                $(".agregar, .nth").show();
            }           
            $('button.agregar_in').last().show();
            
            $('button.eliminar_in').last().show();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $(document).on('keyup','.ed', function() {
            var info = [];
            $('.ed').each(function(){ info.push($(this).val()); });
            $(".edad_hidden").val(info);
        });


        function add_control(contenedor){
            ctr = ctr + 1;
            contenedor.append('<div class="btun"><input type="number" min="0" class="ed" name="edades[]" value=""  id="tb' + ctr + '' +'"/>'+
                              '<button class="agregar_in">+</button>'+
                              '<button class="eliminar_in">-</button></div>');
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div id="slider" style="width:500px;background:red"></div>

    <form method="post">
      <p class="nth" style="display: inline-block;">Agregar</p>
      <button class="agregar">+</button>
      <div class="inputs"></div>
      <input type="hidden" value  class="edad_hidden"></input>   
     <!-- <input type="submit" value="enviar" /> -->
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edito con tu comentario, en ese caso, en el `contenedor.append` añade el slider y cuando pulses el botón "+" llama al método `.slider()` para crearlo. Aprovecha que tienes la variable `ctr` para asignarles un `id` a cada `slider` para poder seleccionarlos individualmente.

```js
   $( function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
  } );


 var ctr = 0;
        var ctr_bdra = 0;
        var init = 0;
        var contenedor = $(".inputs");
        var edad = $(".edad_hidden");
        var edades;

        $(".agregar").click(function(e){            
            add_control(contenedor);
            $(".agregar, .nth").hide(); 
            e.preventDefault();

        });


        $(document).on('click', 'button.agregar_in', function(e){
            if($(".ed").val() == "")
            {
                return false;

            }else{
                add_control(contenedor);
                ctr_bdra = 1;
                if(ctr_bdra > 0){
                    $(this).hide();
                    
                    $(this).next().hide();
                }
        $( ".slid" ).slider();
            }
            e.preventDefault();

        });

        $(document).on('click', 'button.eliminar_in', function(e){ 

            array = $(".edad_hidden").val().split(',');
            array.pop();
            $(".edad_hidden").val(array);
            var node = $(this).parent();
            node.remove();
            if(!$(".slid").is(":visible")){
                $(".agregar, .nth").show();
            }           
            $('button.agregar_in').last().show();
            
            $('button.eliminar_in').last().show();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $(document).on('keyup','.ed', function() {
            var info = [];
            $('.ed').each(function(){ info.push($(this).val()); });
            $(".edad_hidden").val(info);
        });


        function add_control(contenedor){
            ctr = ctr + 1;
            console.log(ctr);
            contenedor.append('<div id="slider'+ctr+'" class="slid" style="width:500px;background:red">'+
                              '<button class="agregar_in">+</button>'+
                              '<button class="eliminar_in">-</button></div>');
        }
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div id="slider" style="width:500px;background:red"></div>

    <form method="post">
    <br/>
      <p class="nth" style="display: inline-block;">Agregar</p>
      <button class="agregar">+</button>
      <div class="inputs"></div>
      <input type="hidden" value  class="edad_hidden"></input>   
     <!-- <input type="submit" value="enviar" /> -->
    </form>
```

Comment: NO   ESO NO QUIERO , LO QUE QUIERO es : ese slider aparezca en vez de los inputs , osea cuando doy clic en el boton agregar sale un slider luego  doy clic en el boton +  agrega o muestra otro slider , y asi sucesivamente , muestra varios sliders